# Python typing by line effect

Tags: python, ascii

I already learnt how to do a type effect:

```
words = '''
      Example
      Example.
      '''
for char in words:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I want to know if it is possible to do this not by characters, but by complete lines? I have a massive ASCII image, and when I do it by character it is either too fast or too slow.

**EDIT**


The end result I want to achieve is a effect that types out a full line instantly, then  waits a little bit to print out the next line, like the example except with whole lines instead of characters.

Comment: `words.split('\n')` ?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what final result you want. But what about printing by batch of `N` chars at a given frequency (equal to `1/0.05` in your example) and then playing with these two parameters until you get what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for line in words.split('\n'):
   time.sleep(0.05)
   sys.stdout.write(line + '\n')
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define `words` the way you are currently, then you can simply split the string by each newline character and print each line that way:

```
for line in words.split('\n'):
    time.sleep(0.05)
    sys.stdout.write(line + '\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Otherwise, you could define `words` as, say, a list:

```
words = [
    'Example',
    'Example.'
    ]
```

which works similarly as far as code spacing and readability is concerned, and would allow you to use the code you already have for printing out the list.

Comment: There is also a built-in string function `splitlines()`, i.e. `words.splitlines()`.

Comment: It works, but it butchers my ASCII image. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Ah, forgot that `split()` removes the character from each of its strings, so suddenly all the newlines disappear. @wdowling has the correct answer here; I'll edit my solution to fix that, as well.